# Determining whether a port is closed (no one is listening) or iptables reject my host

Tags: tcp, iptables

Can I tell whether the service I'm calling has a reject rule in its iptables or it doesn't listen on the port I'm calling?

it seems that I always get icmp port unreachable

Comment: it would be helpful if down voters explained in what way this question is not good

Answer (score 1):

Is possible that Iptables has a rule to drop ICMP packets. If you want to be sure You can do a port scanning (with *nmap* for example) assuming that the host is alive and avoiding the send of ICMP packets. 
For example:

```
nmap -Pn -p 80 -sT 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: nmap replies on both cases with: state:filtered

Answer (score 1):

There is no ambiguity. ICMP PORT UNREACHABLE would come from a firewall rule. ECONNREFUSED would be caused by penetrating the firewall and finding nothing listening at the port.

Comment: Can you make ECONNREFUSED with an iptables firewall rule?